# Property can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be null

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am trying to address the `null` safety on the following function. Nesting `if` statements doesn't seem to work.

```
bool doesTourExceedsVenueCapacity(
  ToursRecord? tourRecord,
  int? venueCapacity,
) {
 
  return tourRecord.passengers > venueCapacity ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both of your values are nullable you have to adjust your code to do the conditional check. Add some guard-like checks before:

```dart
bool doesTourExceedsVenueCapacity(
  ToursRecord? tourRecord,
  int? venueCapacity,
) {
  final passengers = tourRecord?.passengers;
  if (venueCapacity == null) return false //adjust return value
  if (passengers == null) return false // adjust return value
 
  return passengers > venueCapacity; // ? true : false unnecessary here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the statement that you check `tourRecord.passengers > venueCapacity` contains two values that can be null. `ToursRecord? tourRecord.passengers` and `int? venueCapacity`. The question mark is important.

Answer (score 0):

Either Remove null or add condition to handle nullable type in your condition.

Example (By removing nullable type)

```
bool doesTourExceedsVenueCapacity(
  ToursRecord tourRecord,
  int venueCapacity,
) {
 
  return tourRecord.passengers > venueCapacity ? true : false;
}
```